# DomParser from string XML getting null document

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm trying to parse a xml string using domParser but when I trying to get the document it shows [#document: null] and it doesn't contain the data of xml passing.

The code is something like that:

```
Document doc = null;
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
logger.debug("Parsing");
InputSource IS = new InputSource(new StringReader(nameFile));            
parser.parse(IS);
doc = parser.getDocument();
NodeList NL = doc.getElementsByTagName("element");
```

The problem starts when doc = parser.getDocument().
It returns [#document=null]. So the NodeList can't find the element that I'm looking for.
My XML is quite big. It contains around 50K character.
My question is, what are the possible issue that introducing this problem?

For your information, this application with the same code works in OAS with JDK1.4 now I'm transfering the application to Weblogic 12c with JDK 1.6.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:
Sorry for not mentioning nameFile data type. nameFile is a xml data in string format.

UPDATED2:
I've tried with a simple xml but no luck.
Example:
1st Example: this string is without any space ->

```
nameFile = "<?xml version='1.0'?><company><staff id='1001'><firstname>yong</firstname><lastname>mook kim</lastname><nickname>mkyong</nickname><salary>100000</salary></staff><staff id='2001'><firstname>low</firstname><lastname>yin fong</lastname><nickname>fong fong</nickname><salary>200000</salary></staff></company>";
```

2nd Example:

```
nameFile = "<message>Hello</message>
```

None of this is working. Always returns [#document:null]

Comment: `toString()` on DOM classes is almost useless.

Comment: I didn't mentioned any toString() here. I've a string that contains xml data. I've to put it on the "doc" to get specific elements to a NodeList to do some process with those data.

Comment: You may not be calling `toString()` explicitly but it gets called by Java automatically in an expression like `System.out.println(doc)`, or if you're running your code under a debugger then that will often use the `toString` representation to display variable values.  If you want to write out a DOM node as XML then you have to use another API, either `javax.xml.transform` with a no-op `Transformer`, or the `org.w3c.dom.ls` "load and store" mechanism.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for reply... now it looks a bit clear. I'm using debugger to see all the values.. but still I'm confused why it's not working even I run the application without debugger. NodeList NL= doc.getElementsByTagName("element"); I'm not getting anything. if I look at NL.item(0) i get element=null and NL.item(1) = null and NL.getLength() = 1

Comment: Again, you _are_ getting the right thing - `[element=null]` is the `toString` representation of an element node whose name is "element" (for an element node, the `nodeName` is the name of the element and the `nodeValue` is always null by definition).  So `doc.getElementsByTagName("element")` has returned you a `NodeList` containing a single item, which itself is an "element" element.

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer in the question exactly what information you're trying to extract from this XML, and then someone may be better able to suggest a sequence of method calls that will retrieve what you want.  So far all you've shown us is the DOM API working exactly as it is supposed to work.

Comment: @IanRoberts - Ya I got the idea of [element=null]. actually I'm confused because with this same code it was working before  with jdk1.4 in a IAS server. But now I'm moving it to a Weblogic 12c with JDK1.6. and the most confusing thing is... yesterday it worked once after that I'm not getting the data I had to. As you said NodeList has data of element then the index of the element should be "0". So let me try with the 0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'nameFile' in your code snippet is a string! The following works perfectly for me.

```
String nameFile= "<message>HELLO World</message>";
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
try {
    parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(nameFile)));
    Document doc = parser.getDocument();
    String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // handle SAXException 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle IOException 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Roopa for the answer. You are right, nameFile is a string that contains xml data. But the problem is that Document doc = parser.getDocument() is returning null. Thats why the next line where you've added getTextContent() to a string doesn't work. because of the null doc. I had to put this doc elements to a nodelist. and No success yet :(

Comment: @NadimAseqAArman no, `parser.getDocument()` is not returning `null`, it's returning a non-null object whose toString() representation is `[#document=null]`.  This is fine, it looks to me like a reasonable `toString()` representation of any `Document` node (the `nodeName` of a document node is always `#document` and its `nodeValue` is always null, see the table at the top of the javadocs for org.w3c.dom.Node).